# TkInter. Elements from a window draw in other window

Tags: python, class, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class m_window:
    
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.geometry('750x500')
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        new_transaction = tk.Button(text = 'New Transaction',width = 25, height = 3, command = lambda: s_window(tk.Tk()))
        new_transaction.pack(side = 'top', padx = 8, pady = 8)
        
        transaction_name = tk.Listbox(width = 80, selectbackground = "#00B9FF")
        transaction_name.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'both', padx = 2,)
        transaction_kind = tk.Listbox(width = 25, selectbackground = "#00B9FF")
        transaction_kind.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'both', padx = 2)
        transaction_amount = tk.Listbox(width = 20, selectbackground = "#00B9FF")
        transaction_amount.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'both', padx = 2)

        transaction_amount.insert(tk.END, "hOLA")

class s_window:
    def __init__(self, swindow):
        self.wind = swindow
        self.wind.geometry('375x175')
        self.widgets2()

    def widgets2(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(text = 'l')
        self.label.pack(side = 'left')


obj_m_window = m_window(tk.Tk())
obj_m_window.wind.mainloop()
```

That label was just to test, and y I want it to appear in the second window but appear in the main window when I click de the button to open the second window.

Comment: You need to specify the *master* or *parent* of the widget, otherwise it will be the root window by default. Also avoid creating multiple instances of `Tk`.

Comment: How I specify the master?

Comment: Pass it as the first argument when creating the widget, like `new_transaction = tk.Button(self.wind, text="...", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

> That label was just to test, and y I want it to appear in the second
> window but appear in the main window when I click de the button to
> open the second window

In line 30. Add object `self.label = tk.Label(self.wind,....`

Change this:

```
self.label = tk.Label(text = 'l')
```

to:

```
self.label = tk.Label(self.wind, text = 'Hello, Kumar López l')
```

Screenshot:

[image]